# Ratio of Forces

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics

**Problem.** An object is dropped from a building. After travelling $\text{10 m}$ freely, a force $F_1$ is applied on the object for $1$ second and the object comes to rest. If one would apply another force $F_2$ for $2$ seconds instead of $F_1,$ the body would come to rest. Find $F_1:F_2.$

*Progress.* We know that $v^2=u^2+2as.$

After travelling $10$ meters, the velocity of the object would be $\sqrt{0^2+2\times 9.8\times 10}=14\text{ m/s.}$

Now, moment of force = change of momentum.

This gives $F_1\times 1=F_2\times 2=\text{Mass of the object}\times 14\implies F_1:F_2=2:1.$

But the given answer says $F_1:F_2=17:12.$

Please point out my error.

**Edit.** Mr. Basu turned out to be right!

Actually, moment of net force = change in momentum.

This means $(F_1-mg)\times 1=(F_2-mg)\times 2=14m.$

$\implies F_1=m(g+14)~;~F_2=m(g+7).$

$\implies F_1:F_2=(g+14):(g+7)=17:12.$

Comment: The force of gravity acts at the same time as the forces $F_1$ and $F_2$ are acting and so contributes to the impulse.

Comment: @Eshan Add gravity (ie subtract weight) in both cases and see if it works.

Comment: Hi Eeshan and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: (g+14) : (g+7) should be 24:17

Comment: Remember $g = 9.8 m s^{-2}.$ But you're plugging $g=10 m s^{-2}.$

Answer (score 0):

I think that this question is not homework question as @Eeshan has posted his procedure for solving the question. So this question deserves an explanation.

My answer:

The velocity of the particle after the fall of $10m$ is $10\sqrt{2}\frac{m}{s}$.

Let Force $F_1$ and $F_2$ produce an acceleration of $a_1$ and $a_2$ respectively.

Using the formula, $v=u+at$, and the fact that final velocity '$v$' is $0$ for both the cases, we get,

$at=-u$

For $F_1$,

$(a_1-10)1=10\sqrt{2}$

Similarly for $F_2$,

$(a_2-10)2=10\sqrt{2}$

On dividing the values of $a_1$ and $a_2$ , you will get,

$\frac{F_1}{F_2}=\frac{ma_1}{ma_2}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{1}$

But, $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{1}=\frac{17}{12}\approx1.41$,

$\frac{F_1}{F_2}=\frac{17}{12}$.

So, you missed to include the effect of gravitation while solving your question.

And also, your edit is correct as $\frac{24}{17}\approx1.41$

Comment: Why the velocity of the particle will be $10\sqrt{2}ms^{-1}?$ According to my calculation, the velocity should be $14ms^{-1}.$

Comment: V^2=2 x 10 x 10.

Comment: But $g$ is NOT given to be $10\text{ m s}^{-1}.$ You just can't assume it.

Comment: Do what you want. Do not focus on this too much. It won't change your answer rather it would just bring a slight variance.

Comment: Then I ask the moderators to lock this post down, the question is solved.